# Reciprocate Links on aggregation in MS SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have a table named *Calls* with 2 columns, `caller` and `receiver`. A sample of it would be like this:

```
Caller |  Receiver
A      |    B
B      |    A
C      |    D 
A      |    C
A      |    B
```

How can I aggregate my data in a way I can get the count of the calls of 2 persons. With the previous sample, it would be like this (*order A-B or B-A does not matter):

```
Caller* |  Receiver*  | count(*)
    A      |    B     |  3
    A      |    C     |  1
    C      |    D     |  1
```

I have tried some self joins and seen some similar (but different examples for mySQL), but I can´t do it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select caller,receiver,count(*)
from (
   select case 
            when caller < receiver then caller
            else receiver
          end as caller, 
          case
             when caller > receiver then caller
             else receiver 
          end as receiver
   from calls
) t
group by caller, receiver
order by caller, receiver;
```

It would be a bit shorter (and more readable) if SQL Server supported `least()` and `greatest()`.

Comment: That´s perfect. Thank you!  I´ve seen some examples with those functions and they did look more simple.

Comment: Imagine I have a third column denoting the difference between voice call and sms. If I want to quantify it like, if it´s sms, count =0.5, if it is a voice call, count = 1. Can I incorporate it here?